# How do Java methods using who passed them in them

Tags: java, methods

I'm sorry if this title doesn't describe the problem properly but I wasn't sure how to describe it.

I have a method called `changeToWhite()` that can be called on a Piece 
e.g. `Piece.changeToWhite()`

but for me to be able to change the piece to white I need access to the piece so I decided to pass it in as an argument 
e.g. `Piece.changeToWhite(Piece)`

The passing in as an argument seems unnecessary.

The `toUpperCase()` functions does it somehow e.g. `someString.toUpperCase()`

How can I do this?

Comment: You can use the keyword `this` to refer to an object, within a method that was called on that object.  Is that what you're asking; if not, please clarify.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you define `changeToWhite` on a `Piece` class, then on an instance you can use `this` to get the reference to the current object.  Something like:

```
class Piece {
    private String color;
    ...
    public void changeToWhite() {
       this.color = 'white';
    }
}
```

Note that when you define a method on a class, you need to have an **instance** on which to call the methods.

So

```
Piece piece1 = new Piece();
piece1.changeToWhite();
```

Note that the Java standard is to use uppercase to define a class (e.g. `Piece`), and camel case (e.g. `changeToWhite`) for instance methods and fields.

The OTHER way to do it would be to use a static method.  In this case, the method belongs to the class, it doesn't have a `this` context like instance methods do

```
class Piece {
   private String color; // instance field


   /**
       Takes a piece instance as an argument, and operates on that.
    */
   private static void changeToWhite(Piece piece) {
      piece.setColor('white'); // assume setColor exists
   }

}
```

but the first way is preferable.

Answer (score 3):

This is the difference between static and instance methods. In your example, calling `Piece.changeToWhite()` is a static method, but you are trying to access instance variables (the type of piece).

You have two choices:

1. Do as you describe and pass in the piece you want to change.
2. Make it an instance method and then do something like `Piece p1 = new Piece(); p1.changeToWhite();`